# Show that the barycenters of ABC and DEF coincide.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Given a triangle $ABC$, consider the triangle $DEF$ where $B$ is the midpoint of $AD$, $A$ is the midpoint of $CF$ and $C$ is the midpoint of $BE$. Show that the barycenters of $ABC$ and $DEF$ coincide.

Obs: Use plan geometry

I have by vectors. I need by plan geometry

The midpoint is given by
$\vec{X}=\dfrac{\vec{X}+\vec{Y}}{2}$

$\vec{A}=\dfrac{\vec{C}+\vec{F}}{2}$

$  \vec{B}=\dfrac{\vec{A}+\vec{D}}{2}$

$\vec{C}=\dfrac{\vec{B}+\vec{E}}{2}$

$ \therefore \dfrac{\vec{A}+\vec{B}+\vec{C}}{3}=  \dfrac{\vec{D}+\vec{E}+\vec{F}}{3} \implies$

$\vec{G}_{ABC}=\vec{G}_{DEF}$

[image]

Comment: So you have the question and the answer...

Comment: $X=\dfrac{X+Y}{2}$ only happens if $X=Y$. You probably didn't mean that.

Comment: @JeanMarie  I need the solution by plane geometry

Comment: @jjagmath The presented solution I found on the net, I cannot guarantee that it is correct so I need the solution by plane geometry

Answer (score 2):

If you wonder why the solution you found on the Internet, is working, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015015/show-for-the-centroid-m-of-a-triangle-abc-that-vecom-frac13-vecoa-v) and [this one](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2014/Kirk/Assigment%204/Exploration%20Number%204.htm)
will probably help you understand the solution. If you still cannot convince yourself that the solution is working, you may adopt a new analytic approach explained below.

WLOG, we may assume that $A=(-1,0), C=(1,0),$ and $B=(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Of course, at this step, you must persuade yourself why defining a triangle in such a way covers all of the possible cases.

Since  [the centroid divides in $2:1$ ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320782/how-to-prove-using-plane-geometry-that-centroid-divides-in-ratio-21), the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ is $(\frac{a}{3}, \frac{b}{3}).$

Now, we also have:

$$F=(-3,0),\\ E=(2-a,-b), \\ D=(1+2a,2b).$$

So, the midpoint of $FE$ is:

$$(\frac{-1-a}{2},\frac{-b}{2});$$

and the centroid of $\triangle FED$ is:

$$(\frac{2(\frac{-1-a}{2})+(1+2a)}{3}, \frac{2(\frac{-b}{2})+(2b)}{3})=(\frac{a}{3}, \frac{b}{3}).$$

Note that in the last line, we calculated a third of the segment between the midpoint of $FE$ and $D$.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and for the links, but as mentioned, I would like a solution by plane geometry and not by analytical or vector geometry

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: It can be shown that resulting triangle by extending each side of a triangle equal to itself is similar to original one. As shown in figure if you continue this you will get third triangle similar to original one. The position of all points like orthocenter, circumcircle and incenter vary due to scale of triangle, but centroid remains fixed at its original position. In fact we have a kind of affine transformation(https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineTransformation.html) by rotating about centroid and enlargement.